ASP.NET Web API : POST method - how to post list of multipart form-data with image?
I'm making personal project to create multi image with text cards(Like quizlet with image). I've written a POST method to create multiple cards at a time.
My current method is:
[HttpPost("bulk-create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BulkCreate([FromForm] BulkCreateIdeaCardsDTO ideaCardsDTO)
{
    //...
}

My DTOs:
public class BulkCreateIdeaCardsDTO
{
    public List<CreateIdeaCardDTO> IdeaCards { get; set; }
}

public class CreateIdeaCardDTO
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Image { get; set; }
}

It seems that it does not allow me to input multiple form-data as shown in this screenshot:
Swagger request body
So I'm trying to figure out how to create multiple cards.... Could I input multiple form-data? Or is there any other way to handle this situation?

After investigating the issue, this problem is related to swagger ui, and use IFormFile with nested objects is not currently supported..
Here is my solution
public class BulkCreateIdeaCardsDTO
{
    public List<string>? Contents { get; set; } 
    public List<IFormFile>? Images { get; set; }
}

Test Result

Reason and Suggestion
Because your API interface is normal in Postman, this problem has nothing to do with our backend code, but is related to the display of the front-end page (Swagger UI). So if you are interested in this feature, you can submit a feature request in its github.

Thank you! I got it now
